# XML Beautifier for vim?

Tags: vim, xml

Is there a vim command or plugin that quickly "beautifies" XML?

I have a file that looks like

```
<parent><child attr="bla"><subitem>Hello!
</subitem></child>
</parent>
```

and I want to make it look like

```
<parent>
  <child attr="bla">
    <subitem>Hello!
    </subitem>
  <child>
<parent>
```

Answer (score 10):

Using only vim builtins:

First replace all >< with > [newline] < :

```
:%s/></>\r</g
```

Then to reindent:

```
gg=G
```

These steps give me the right output for your example data.

Comment: Not sure why but the gg=G is not working for me.  I also tried it on a small bock but the = command is not working.

Comment: Does == work on a single line? Maybe try :set ft=xml to set indent rules.